# Does "Are thousands of times a charm?" sound correct?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, phrases

I want to interpret the idiom "the third time's a charm" differently by questioning whether, if you did it a thousand times/thousands of times, it would then be a charm. So is putting it like "Are thousands of times a charm?" correct? Or is "Would a thousand times be a charm?" correct?

Comment: I'd say 'The third time's **the** charm' _strongly_ resists variation (as all idioms do to some extent).  'Would a thousand times be the charm?' sounds at best wry, but probably over-clever. 'Charm' in this sense is very rare.

Comment: Both your suggestions are grammatically valid, and the semantic difference between "is X Y" and "would X be Y" is minimal but obvious. If you want to ask about the difference between simple and conditional tenses, please edit to focus on that (and perhaps it would be more appropriate on English Language Learners). And any time you "riff" creatively on an established idiom, it's likely to work only if the existing idiom has already been recently referenced.

Comment: Of course not. **Third here implies *first and second***. So, thousand does not work at all. I won't bother with an answer since this appears so obvious to me and is just explanation of an idiom.

Comment: Would *Would a thousand times be a charm?" [be] correct?* Yes, it would be. It maintains the parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

I view *the third time's the charm* as a somewhat humorous take on the expression *works like a charm*:

**the third time is the charm** (idiom)

> *US*
> Used to say that two efforts at something have already failed but
> perhaps the third will be successful [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20third%20time%20is%20the%20charm)

**work like a charm** (idiom)

> To produce a desired result very easily and effectively: to work very
> well
>
> *The cleaning fluid worked like a charm on the carpet stain.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/work%20like%20a%20charm)

We say "Third time's the charm" after a couple of attempts at a task that fail, often because of obvious mistakes, e.g., after first putting a key in a lock upside down and then locking the door because it was already open. The point is that if something is truly a "charm," it should work on the first attempt. Perhaps there is an allusion to *superstition* or an *incantation* that has to be repeated three times to work. Note that m-w and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/third_time_is_the_charm) label "Third time is the charm" as *US*.

I have said something like "Twentieth time's the charm" when a task has succeeded *after* there have been *many* repeated attempts with  considerable effort, research, or trial and error. You could say "The thousandth time's the charm" with a similar ironic intent (although "thousandth time" doesn't exactly roll off the tongue.) I think any variation you try should stay in the form of "The *nth* time's the charm" so the original idiom can be recognized.

Comment: Some usage examples of "the thousandth time's the charm" [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+thousandth+time%27s+the+charm%22&sxsrf=APq-WBs6Lb8NgdcrFOErTKo6SwcGeJJcNw:1648557566299&filter=0&biw=1536&bih=714&dpr=1.25&safe=active).

Comment: @Justin Thanks. Yes, I caught the song title when searching :-)

Comment: The number three has mystical significance to some people, so I don't think we can just pick any number without losing the meaning of the expression. Magicians say spells three times in some mythologies. Trinities play important parts in everything from Shakespeare to the Christian Bible.

Comment: @ColleenV - British soldiers in the trenches in Flanders 1914-1918 used to say that having the third light from a shared match for your cigarette was unlucky. Some say it's because, at night, the first one got a German sniper's attention, the second one he took aim, and at the third one he fired.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Interesting. I've never heard that one. Superstitions (and human 
 minds) are strange. This photography article argues that three is a magic number when reading images based on "cognitive science" and how our brains like to group things: https://www.institute-of-photography.com/three-magic-number-rule-threes-composition/

Comment: "In threes" is pretty pervasive, e.g., spitting three times to ward off evil in Islamic and Jewish tradition. And yes, it's a good "chunk" for the brain to manage and in esthetics--art/poetry/rhetoric, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=105649751), where I searched for `* * BE the charm` (and also without the definite article), there is some variation on the expression. However, I was not able to find examples with "times", as in the plural.

The variations I see are:

- It can be any number ("twentieth time", "82nd time")
- The number takes either the definite or null articles ("the second time", "6th time")
- Both the definite and indefinite articles are used with "charm". I don't see any difference between them. Note that in speech these can sound very similar ("a charm", "the charm")
- A variety of tenses are used as appropriate, both contracted and full form ("time is", "time'll be", "time was")
- Sometimes instead of "ordinal number + time", it's a "ordinal number + different noun", a phrase containing a cardinal number, or just a cardinal number. The last one is in essence an ellipsis. ("3rd try is the charm", "number 10 will be the charm", "9's the charm")

While I didn't search for questions (the rules should be the same but not the word order), "will the thousandth time be a charm?" seems fine to me. Here's a similar example: [Will the Fourth Time Be a Charm? - Science](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.253.5020.623)